# Android: copying the existing LinearLayout on button click

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want the existing `LinearLayout` with text and buttons inside to be copied on button click, like in Task manager apps when you create a new task.

Can I delete this copied layout from the button *inside* this `LinearLayout`? I know you can create new screen element etc. but can you do it this way?

Comment: Please specify from where to where you want to copy this `View`. It would be very useful if you attach some code snippets here. You can [remove](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeView(android.view.View)) `View` from `ViewGroup` parent and [add](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View)) it to another.

Comment: You need to learn about fragments and custom views. These allow you to create multiple copies of the same XML layout.